# How can space strech a wave?

Tags: electromagnetism

Because of the expanding of the universe a wave from a far galaxy or star can be streched to more red. But how is space doing that? There must be a kind of 'entanglement' between the wave and space. But what is that? And if that is true can you say that the speed of light is bordered by space itself?

Answer (score 0):

The "entanglement" is that "red" or "blue" or such things are dependent on the wavelength of the light, and the "length" part of a wavelength is a spatial measure. In our universe it appears that space is "stretching" (expanding, in the usual terminology) and it stretches the wavelengths of various waves along with it. The stretching is very slight, though, so we only notice it for waves that travel a long distance to reach us - and that is pretty much exclusive to electromagnetic waves, though perhaps soon we will detect gravitational waves as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are streching the carpet below a line of walking ants, this changes the distance between ants, i.e., the wavelenght of the ants line.

The entanglement is "being at a place in space" (at a given moment).

Comment: But I don't see 'fields' without 'grass'.  Space can only stretch if it contains (dark) energy.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question and answer.
Anyway what you say is not not true: dark energy is not the only element causing expansion (and its additional role seems to accelerate it).